# iOS Objective C AdHoc Distribution How to Read Certificate Expiration

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, certificate, adhoc

I have several iOS apps for use in-house by a particular client that are provided in an AdHoc manner.  As devices get added I generate a new mobile provisioning file. At times I will also generate a new certificate, especially as the current one comes close to expiration.  Rather than embed in code a date check that matches against that specific certificates expiration so I can alert the user perhaps 30 days in advance to request an update, I'd like to be able to read that information from within/thru the app and thus not be bound to any specific certificate, just the one currently configured for use with their instance. Is getting the expiry date possible from within the iOS app via Objective C?